# Android installReferrer

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play

Мне необходимо чтобы можно было определить, что некоторый пользователь установил приложение по ссылке от реферера.

Я использовал Install Referrer Library.

Но я не могу понять, какую ссылку нужно генерировать, которую потом нужно отправлять для приглашения людей

Отправляю по

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.....&hl=ru&referrer=example_referral_code_here

Но в запущенном приложении не отображаются в Logax

```
referrerClient = InstallReferrerClient.newBuilder(this).build()
referrerClient.startConnection(object : InstallReferrerStateListener {

    override fun onInstallReferrerSetupFinished(responseCode: Int) {
        when (responseCode) {
            InstallReferrerResponse.OK -> {
                val response: ReferrerDetails = referrerClient.installReferrer
                val referrerUrl: String = response.installReferrer
                val referrerClickTime: Long = response.referrerClickTimestampSeconds
                val appInstallTime: Long = response.installBeginTimestampSeconds
                val instantExperienceLaunched: Boolean = response.googlePlayInstantParam
                Log.d("Response", response.toString())
                Log.d("ReferrerUrl", referrerUrl)
                Log.d("referrerClickTime", referrerClickTime.toString())
                Log.d("appInstallTime", appInstallTime.toString())
                Log.d("instantExperienceLaunched", instantExperienceLaunched.toString())
                referrerClient.endConnection()

                Log.d("NewAuthActivity", response.toString())
            }
            InstallReferrerResponse.FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED -> {
                // API not available on the current Play Store app.
            }
            InstallReferrerResponse.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE -> {
                // Connection couldn't be established.
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onInstallReferrerServiceDisconnected() {
        // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
        // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
    }
})
```

Или нужно сначала в PlayMarket загрузить?

Answer (score 0):

Приложение должно быть инсталлировано по вашей ссылке из Google Play, иначе откуда эти атрибуты возьмутся? Их же библиотека получает из приложения Google Play Store на устройстве.

Генератор ссылок есть здесь
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-url-builder

Comment: ну вот у меня новая версия (с referrer), на Play market старая (без).

Я пользователю скинул ссылку, он установил приложение по ссылку, но в логах у меня не появилось.

Получается мне сначала нужно залить новую версию и только потом уже отправлять ссылки?

Comment: Просто я хотел протестировать, но почему - то не выводился Log. Поэтому я залил версию на внутреннее тестирование и жду пока зальется

Comment: Сейчас попробую ссылку изменить по вашему источнику

Comment: Мне не понятно как вы хотите увидеть что у вашего пользователя в логах. Или о каком логе речь?

Comment: кажется я не так понял. Я думал, что при установке приложения рефералом у реферара эти данные прилетают, и я могу ему вознаграждение сделать, а прочитав ваше последнее сообщение, как я понял, это у вызывается у реферала, верно*